# Will Empathy Stop working with Yahoo Messenger at the End of the Month

Tags: empathy

I use Empathy to chat with various friend and one is on Yahoo. For the last week  or so I have gotten this message each time I login:

yahoomessenger 03:41:04 PM
It’s time to upgrade! Your version of Yahoo Messenger is currently being discontinued, and will no longer work as of August 31, 2016. Get the newest version at https://yho.com/getmessenger to continue using Yahoo Messenger. For more information, go to https://yho.com/YMhel

Does this mean that Empathy will no longer work or is the community working on a fix for whatever Yahoo is doing to Messenger?

Thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: Good question but you might get a better response from the Empathy devs, you can find there contact details here https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Empathy?action=show&redirect=Empathy#Contact_Information If you do get an answer, please feel free to come back and post it here :)